# Android button.setOnClickListener

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabbed-activity

I am making an app for studies with tabbedActivity plus the button is not taking the action, someone knows to explain the reason, I have tried several forms but all are without action, does not give error and breaks the app but the button nothing

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rooView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teste, container, false);
        final Context context = getContext();
        button = (Button) rooView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        return rooView;
    } 

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you implement `OnClickListener` interface?

Comment: yes i implements. `public class Cadastro extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Button button;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rooView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teste, container, false);
        button = (Button) rooView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rooView;
    } 

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btConfirm:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I made the change, even so it continues without action

Comment: it continues what action? i think you dont need the final Context context = getContext(); 

And is your button id in xml named button only?

Comment: I made some changes but continued without action on the button.   xml button`<Button
        android:id="@+id/btConfirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cbTermos"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Confirmar" />`

Comment: can you post your fragment xml? if you don't mind. So the button is not Toasting your toast?

Comment: there you are your id is different to your button. Do this

button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);

Comment: isso mesmo java `@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cadastro, container, false);
        btConfirm = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);
        btConfirm.setOnClickListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }`

Comment: `@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btConfirm:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }`

Comment: No, the button is not Toasting

Comment: instead of getContext in your Toast, change it to getActivity(). Is't ok now?

Comment: Does not display an error. Does not display the toast. I already tried to debug but it does not reach the stretch of toast

Comment: yes `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: the button above? did you change your R.id.button to R.id.btConfirm?

Comment: his, the button name is now btConfirm

Comment: button is your Button variable, you need to cast it to your id. Is this your button code? button = (Button) rooView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);

Comment: `btConfirm = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);`

Comment: use this code button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btConfirm);

Comment: Button button is declared before the View. Look at the code above. I already edit it

Comment: Nothing again, I do not know what else to do